Writing $\ln(x+1)e^{-ax}$ in terms of Meijer-G function
Is there any way to write $f(x)=\ln(x+1)e^{-ax}$ in terms of Meijer-G function? I tried calculating Mellin transform of $f(x)$ to no avail. Frustrated, I used Mathematica to get the following answer
$$\mathscr{M}\left[f(x);s\right] = \frac{G_{3,5}^{5,2}\left(\frac{a^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1-s}{2},-\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2} \\
 0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-s}{2},-\frac{s}{2},-\frac{s}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{4 \pi ^{3/2}}$$
However, now I can't calculate the inverse transform! Is there another way?
Thank you!

If I may ask : what is your goal ? Is it to inverse $y=\log(x+1),e^{-a x}$ ?

I have an improper integral of the form $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$. This is a part of a larger integral, I am trying to write this part in terms of Meijer-G function (I have written the other part in terms of Meijer-G, $g(x)$ is solved), then using the Parseval's theorem for Mellin transform, i.e. $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathcal{L}}F(s)G(1-s)ds$, I can get a result in terms of MEijer-G function for the integral.

Maple says
$$\log (x+1)\cdot \exp (-a x)=x\cdot G_{2,2}^{1,2}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
0,0 \
0,-1 \
\end{array}
\right.\right)\cdot G_{0,1}^{1,0}\left(a x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
0 \
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

@gpmath, thank you, however, that's just the product of each term stated in terms of Meijer-g.
